# JWPlayer 7 - Flash plugin failed to load error

Tags: jwplayer

Getting the error 'flash plugin failed to load' message when using the following, the stream paths test fine with Wowza test players so should be valid. The local paths to jwplayer.js are correct.

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Stream Team Player Test</title>
    <script src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script src="jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf"></script>
    <script>jwplayer.key="xxx";</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="streamContainer">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("streamContainer");
playerInstance.setup({
playlist: [{
        sources: [{ 
            file: "http://xxx:1935/stream-team-dvr/apptest01/manifest.f4m?DVR"
        },{
            file: "http://xxx:1935/stream-team-dvr/apptest01/manifest.m3u8?DVR"
        }]
}],
title: "Stream Team Test",
     description: "This is the files description"
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can omit this line: `<script src="jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf"></script>`

The JW Player js library will determine whether the .swf file is necessary and include it under the hood.

Here is a resource with more info on setting up a basic video embed that you may find helpful: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406723-basic-video-embed

Comment: I have problem with jwplayer 7.4.2 & hls source too. Mac 10.11.4 with Firefox 46.0.1 return error "Failed to setup flash. Error calling method on NPObject" and with Chrome 50.0.2661.102 return error "An invalid exception was trown"

Comment: HLS is not supported in Flash, so you'll need to use the HTML5 player, which is the default, or in the setup config, you can set "primary": "html5".

Comment: Mac firefox getting error "Flash plugin failed to load"

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati did you manage to solve your problem, I know it was over a year ago but I got the same problem and can't find a solution

Comment: @demsey same here I did not find.

Answer (score 0):

JWPlayer uses `html5` player by default. If its not able to play the video using html5 it goes for flash player which you have specified.

```
jwplayer('video').setup(
  file: 'file/path'
  flashplayer: '/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf'
)
```

By default it will search for flashplayer in `'/'`

More details [here](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/#rendering-and-loading)